# 1K views, what happened?

Tags: discussion

The last 30 questions or so, all got at most 50 views. Except one particular question: "[What's really meant by context-free in the term context-free grammar?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/68231)" which got +1K views.

What happened here?

Comment: It probably went hot, attracting view from all over the network. Shallow questions often do.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_effect

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a sign that the question has been advertised somewhere popular. In this case, it was automatically picked up on the [hot network questions](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot). A random selection of HNQ is shown in the sidebar on the front page, question pages and several other pages of every Stack Exchange site. HNQ can draw quite a crowd that doesn't normally care for the site.

[Hot network questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/hot-questions/info) are picked [automatically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) based on [answer count, question and answer score, age, and some balancing criteria to compensate for differences in site voting patterns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page). Because being on the HNQ list brings more visitors who vote, there's a feedback effect that tends to accentuate and self-perpetuate the HNQ effect.

In practice, HNQ tends to pick up questions whose title is either easy to understand or funny. It favors broad, easy-to-understand (but not necessarily easy-to-answer) questions that appeal to a wide audience of non-experts, not at all the same kind of questions that's popular with site regulars.